# Is it possible to make JQUERY UI DIALOG active on close of its parent window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, jquery-dialog

Below is my requirement:
My parent window loads list of audios files that needs to be played.
When the user would like to play an audio file on click of play button, i am loading a jquery dialog box with an audio player inside of it. I am able to play the audio file. 
**draggable: true,
autoOpen: false,
modal: false,**
In made the modal property false in the jquery dialog, if the user clicks on another audio file the new audio file is loading.
The issue is, if the user closes the parent window, the dialog box is also getting closed. Is there is any way to make the dialog box independent of parent window.
Thanks

Comment: need to be more specific... parent window of dialog is browser window. WHen it closes page is gone

Comment: that's correct charlietfl. is there any way to make the dialog box independent of its parent window(browser window)?

Comment: no.... dialog is just a `<div>` in html. You could use cookie or local storage to track video state and check storage status when page loads and use that test to open dialog and set video if needed.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion charlietfl. i will try to implement.

Comment: Or maybe, you can use a `window.open` method to display your player instead of dialog. Thus, if user close the parent window, your "child window" won't close. More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open